# Logger is not working for biz-talk solution completely

Tags: logging, log4net, biztalk

I am facing one strange issue in my project.There is one solution say S1.Inside that solution there is one biztalk project say P1 and one helper library project.Inside that helper library project we have  one class file for creating log.
Now there is one more solution say S2 .Inside this solution we have two more biztalk projects. say P2 and P3 respectively These biztalk project have reference to that previous project as well as the helper library.
Now the issue is i am able to create log for P2 project but not for the P3 project.

Can anyone please guide me why this is happening??

Thanxs in Advance.

Comment: Debug the project P3 to see if the log shapes are hit. Check the event viewer to see if you have some exception there. Without more detail is impossible that we can help you.

Comment: One thing i observed is that in Biztalk Admin console for this P3 project ideally it should show dependencies for helper library project but it is not showing that and i am not getting why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are logging to the same file. If so, the best solution is to write to different files. An other option is to use a different locking model on the log file.

This example shows how to configure the appender to use the minimal locking model that allows multiple processes to write to the same file.

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="${TMP}\log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

This example shows how to configure the appender to use the "inter process" locking model. Be sure all loggers are using the same locking model.

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="${TMP}\log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+InterProcessLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: One thing i observed is that in Biztalk Admin console for this P3 project ideally it should show dependencies for helper library project but it is not showing that and i am not getting why this is happening